# Concise if else in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda, infix-notation, code-complexity

Is there a way to remove this `if else` block inside snackbar by replacing it with `lambda` or `infix` or anything to make it without +2 nesting in cognitive complexity

```
else {
snackBarBuilder(
                    activities,
                    "failure",
                    "Sorry, text " + if (classofobj.innerclass.toString() == "1") {
                        "good"
                    } else {
                        "bad"
                    }
                )
    }
```

Comment: Extract if-else part to new function (could be a nested function if it's only meaningful in the context of the function building the Snackbar) and use string interpolation. `"Sorry, text ${f()}"`. Something like that

Comment: this code doesn't look particularly good either way, you're not using strings to localize what you're showing, so adding support for different languages won't be possible here, and secondly you have logic in the showing of your snackbar, which just makes it more complicated to test. why not just create a function to determine the string and then pass _all_ relevant data to your snackbar so that it just shows what it should

Comment: Sure Thanks AlirezaFarahani and a_local_nobody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own generic [ternary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:):

```kotlin
fun <T> ternary(predicate: () -> Boolean, trueCase: () -> T, falseCase: () -> T) =
    if (predicate()) {
        trueCase()
    } else {
        falseCase()
    }
```

and then use it like so:

```kotlin
ternary({ true }, { "was true" }, { "was false" })
    .also { println(it) } // prints: was true

// or

"Sorry, text " + ternary( { classofobj.innerclass.toString() == "1"} , {"good"}, {"bad"} )
```

You can also have an `infix` variant but I doubt that it makes things more readable **and** it has [some precedence strings attached](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#infix-notation) :

```kotlin
infix fun <T> (() -> Boolean).ternary(tfOptions: List<() -> T>): T =
    when (this()) {
        true -> tfOptions[0]()
        false -> tfOptions[1]()
    }

// and then

val result = { true } ternary listOf({ "was true" }, { "was false" })
println(result) // prints: was true
```

Comment: Wow Will try it. Thanks!

Comment: I tried the generic ternary function, it works like a charm. I committed my code will try infix later one day :) infix is like super advance